# Player won't jump in unity2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

here's my jump code it updates in void Update

```
 void Jump()
{
 if(isgrounded == true)
 {
 amountofjumps = jumps;    
 }
 if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && amountofjumps > 0)
 {
 rb2d.velocity = Vector2.up * jump * Time.deltaTime;
 amountofjumps--;
 }
 else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && amountofjumps == 0 && isgrounded == true)
 {
 rb2d.velocity = Vector2.up * jump * Time.deltaTime;    
 }
 
}
```

here are the variables I use for my jump code

```
bool isgrounded;
public float groundcheckradius;
public LayerMask whatisground;
public float jump;
private int amountofjumps;
public int jumps;
```

here's how I detect the ground

```
 void checkforground()
{ 
isgrounded = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position,Vector2.down, groundcheckradius,whatisground);
   
}
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
Gizmos.color = Color.red;
Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + Vector3.down * groundcheckradius);  
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What are all the inital values of your variables?

Comment: what do you mean by inital values?

Comment: The first value that the variables would be set to

Comment: bool isgrounded = false   groundcheckradius = 0.6       float jump = 67               
                                                                                                                                      
 int jumps    = 1

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is often used for moving object try `rigidbody2d.AddForce()` instead.

```
void Jump()
{
    if (isgrounded == true)
    {
        amountofjumps = jumps;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && amountofjumps > 0 && isgrounded == true)
    {
        rb2d.AddForce(transform.up * jump, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        amountofjumps--;
    }
}
```

Comment: so is jumping not moving? ^^

Answer (score 0):

- First of all `Time.deltaTime` makes no sense when setting a `velocity`. A `velocity` already is frame-rate independent so when you multiply a velocity by `Time.deltaTime` (about 0.017 for 60 fps) it becomes extremely small/slow.
- Secondly currently you overwrite the entire velocity so if your player is moving forward it will completely stop any movement on the X axis.
- And finally when you are grounded you want **always** be able to jump ... not only if `amountofjumps == 0` which will **never** be the case since right before you have set it to `amountofjumps = jumps;`! You don't want to check the `amountofjumps` at all when jumping from the ground!

You would probably rather use e.g.

```c#
// get the current velocoty of the rigidbody
var velocity = rb2d.velocity;
// Only overwrite the Y velocity with the jump
velocity.y =  jump; 
// re-assign the changed vector to the rgidbody
rb2d.velocity = velocity;
```

And then I would change the logic to something like e.g.

```c#
private void Jump()
{
    if(isgrounded)
    {
        amountofjumps = jumps; 
    
        // when you are grounded you can always jump!
        // Not only when the amountofjumps == 0
        // actually when you are grounded the amountofjumps shouldn't matter at all
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            DoJump();
        }  
    }
    // As before while not grounded the amountofjumps is taken into account
    else if(amountofjumps > 0)
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            DoJump();
        }
    }
}

private void DoJump()
{
    // get the current velocoty of the rigidbody
    var velocity = rb2d.velocity;
    // Only overwrite the Y velocity with the jump
    velocity.y =  jump; 
    // re-assign the changed vector to the rgidbody
    rb2d.velocity = velocity;

    // Always reduce the amount of jumps also when jumping from the ground
    amountofjumps--;
}
```